# download an instance of ec2 to local database

Tags: c#, wpf, amazon-ec2

okay. I have a database instance on ec2. I am using c# to code my application. and I need to download the current updated database from ec2 to my local database when clicked on the sync button provided by me. How can I update the local database with values from ec2?

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: ec2 has rds... local one is sql server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your RDS database to MS SQL Server.

If your RDS database is not MS SQL Server, the way to do is to use the "SQL Server Migration Assistant"

More info here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/

If your RDS database is MS SQL server you can just copy your database.  You can follow these steps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Comment: Thank you rico.. Helped a lot.. :)